# Scrapy - no list page, but I know the url for each item page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrape a website. The item page that I want to scrape looks like: http://www.somepage.com/itempage/&page=x. Where `x` is any number from `1` to `100`. Thus, I have an `SgmlLinkExractor` Rule with a callback function specified for any page resembling this.

The website does not have a listpage with all the items, so I want to somehow well scrapy to scrape those urls (from `1` to `100`). This guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640804/python-scrapy-how-to-fetch-an-url-not-via-following-links-inside-a-spider) seemed to have the same issue, but couldn't figure it out.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 6):

You could list all the known URLs in your [`Spider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#spiders) class' [start_urls](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_urls) attribute:

```
class SomepageSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'somepage.com'
    allowed_domains = ['somepage.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.somepage.com/itempage/&page=%s' % page for page in xrange(1, 101)]

    def parse(self, response):
        # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a one time thing, you can create a local html file `file:///c:/somefile.html` with all the links. Start scraping that file and add `somepage.com` to allowed domains.

Alternately, in the parse function, you can return a new Request which is the next url to be scraped.